# SQL - Modify query to get values from an Interval of Time instead of a fixed Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which return an exact time span:

```
SELECT ScanDate FROM tTimes WHERE personId = 5
```

The value for example could be:

```
2016-08-10 16:26:42.000
```

BY using the query below:

```
SELECT executedTime FROM tTimetable as tc
WHERE tc.lastExecutedTime IN (SELECT ScanDate FROM tTimes WHERE personId =5)
```

I would get:

```
SELECT executedTime FROM tTimetable as tc
    WHERE tc.lastExecutedTime  IN (2016-08-10 16:26:42.000)
```

But, I would like to get values from

```
SELECT executedTime FROM tTimetable as tc
        WHERE tc.lastExecutedTime  IN (between 2016-08-10 16:16:42.000 and  2016-08-10 16:36:42.000)So everything which is between the `2016-08-10 16:26:42.000-10sec` and `2016-08-10 16:26:42.000+10secs`
```

How can I archieve this result?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Side note: You should avoid `BETWEEN` and inclusive upper-bounds for [date and time types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially on SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question

```
 SELECT executedTime 
  FROM  tTimetable as tc
  Join (
        Select DateR1 = DateAdd(SECOND,-10,ScanDate)
              ,DateR2 = DateAdd(SECOND,10,ScanDate) 
         FROM tTimes WHERE personId = 5
       ) B
   on  tc.lastExecutedTime between DateR1 and DateR2
```

Comment: This appears to be a correct answer by my reading of the question.  I have no idea why it would be downvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll just need a moment to collect myself...    There all better

Comment: Well, perhaps because you [shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` with date/time types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)?  (Not the downvoter, but it has the potential to muck with the results)  End times should always be exclusive, especially for range queries like this.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Interesting article, however, I have a problem with it.  When converting from higher precision to lower, there will always be rounding issues.  The same happens with decimal  Select cast(25.105 as decimal (5,2)) = 25.11.   I understand that everyone has their dogmas, but just because a -functional- approach is not someone's "cup of tea", it does not warrant a down vote.  That's just arrogance.   Gordon ranked #1 even questioned the down vote.   The only problem is that I have a odd number, I would feel better if it was a nice -5.   Always dig the debate and challenges.  John

Comment: One more thing and I promise to leave you alone.   DateTime range: 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997 Rounded to increments of:  .000, .003, or .007 seconds Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx .  In short, with like data types there is no shame or concern with BETWEEN.   Respectfully, John

Comment: The post isn't talking about rounding from higher to lower, it's talking about what happens when the system compares lower to higher (the opposite of rounding). The system isn't going to round the higher-precision value, because that could result in the wrong results being included/excluded.  Or, think about if you were attempting to do equal-size buckets; an inclusive bound would improperly include some data twice.  Similar reasoning in Dijkstra's post about the traditional way to index arrays.  Note your logic only holds so long as the internals to `DATEADD` don't upcast for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using `exists`:

```
SELECT executedTime
FROM tTimetable as tc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tTimes
              WHERE personId = 5 AND
                    tc.lastExecutedTime BETWEEN DATEADD(second, -10, ScanDate) AND DATEADD(second, 10, ScanDate)
             );
```

Comment: _Please_ [don't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially when dealing with ranges.  Imagine what happens with bucketing!

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . I used `between` because the OP uses between, but you have a good point.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What could be the possible solution without using Between?